# EXISTS operator in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

actually i am having doubt regarding exists operator

there are two tables.

```
CREATE TABLE EMPDETAIL(
EID NUMERIC(8),
NAME VARCHAR(20),
DOB DATE,
ADDRESS VARCHAR(50),
CONTACTNO NUMERIC(13)
)

CREATE TABLE EMPWEBDETAIL(
EID NUMERIC(8),
EMAIL VARCHAR(30),
USERID VARCHAR(10),
PSWORD VARCHAR(10)
)
```

now i want to obtain the employee who have an entry in empdetail table but not in empwebdetail,,

i can do it with joins, subquery, correlated subquery

but i want to do it with exists operator..
the solution is

```
SELECT A.EID, A.NAME FROM EMPDETAIL AS A WHERE EXISTS( SELECT B.EID FROM EMPWEBDETAIL AS B WHERE A.EID = B.EID)
```

THIS WILL GIVE ME THE DESIRED RESULT

MY QUERY IS EXISTS CHECKS ONLY THAT THE EXPRESSION IN PARENTHESES YIELDING SOME RESULTSET OR WE CAN SAY IF IT RETURNS TRUE OR FALSE, WHICH WORKED JUST FINE IN ABOVE CASE

BUT TAKE A LOOK IN SECOND QUERY BELOW..

```
SELECT A.EID, A.NAME FROM EMPDETAIL AS A WHERE EXISTS(SELECT B.EID FROM EMPDETAIL AS B WHERE B.EID IN (111,112,113))
```

ACCORDING TO THE PREVIOUS RESULT IT SHOULD HAVE GIVEN ME THE RECORDS FOR ONLY THESE THREE EMPLOYEES(111,112,113)
BUT RATHER IT IS GIVING THE COMPLETE ROWS OF EMPDETAIL TABLE...

Comment: You should give this question a better Title !!! ***"EXISTS operator in SQL SERVER"*** doesn't actually sounds like a question

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT  A.EID, A.NAME 
FROM    EMPDETAIL AS A 
WHERE   EXISTS(SELECT B.EID FROM EMPWEBDETAIL AS B WHERE A.EID = B.EID) 
AND     A.EID IN (111,112,113)
```

The `exists` clause in the first example works because you're rrelating the two queries with `A.EID = B.EID`.  Keep that and add an additional `WHERE` query filter for the `IN`.

Answer (score 0):

No, Exists will return all rows where the exists part for that row is true.

Thus even

```
SELECT A.EID, A.NAME 
FROM EMPDETAIL AS A 
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT B.EID FROM EMPDETAIL AS B WHERE 1 = 1)
```

would return all rows from `EMPDETAIL`

Have a look at the below demo

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/39523/1)

Answer (score 0):

You still need to join your EXISTS table to the outer query table in order to limit your results.  Your second query needs to be more along the lines of:

```
SELECT A.EID, A.NAME 
FROM EMPDETAIL AS A 
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT B.EID FROM EMPDETAIL AS B 
             WHERE B.EID = A.EID AND B.EID IN (111,112,113))
```

or a better version would be:

```
SELECT A.EID, A.NAME 
FROM EMPDETAIL AS A 
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT B.EID FROM EMPDETAIL AS B WHERE B.EID = A.EID) 
   AND A.EID IN (111,112,113))
```

Comment: i got it sir, but the question is how the inner query (after exists operator) is being related to the outer query via (a.eid = b.eid)..

because exists only checks that the query after that is yielding true or false...

Comment: In your second query example, it isn't being related at all.  As long as you have any entry with an EID of 111, 112, and/or 113 in your EMPDETAIL table, it returns true.  So basically for every row in EMPDETAIL, the EXISTS returns true, resulting in all records being returned if any of those three exist in the table.  In order to limit the results, it must be related to the outer table in some manner.